# Selecting one field and printing all entries

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I currently have an SQL database holding customer data in different columns such as; shop_name, first_name, last_name, address etc. I want to make a drop down box holding a list of all the shop_name entries and when one is selected it prints the other entries on the webpage.
I am currently using `

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "demo");

$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT shop_name From persons");

$row = mysqli_num_rows($sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
echo "<option value='". $row['shop_name'] ."'>" .$row['shop_name'] ."</option>" ;

}?>`
```

to create the drop down box but I am unsure how to go about printing the other entries.

Comment: What 'other entries' are we talking about? Just the rest of the query results?

Comment: you need js for this, or use a POST/GET array with a form to pass to another page.

Comment: you need ajax for this since you will be dependent on the chosen dropdown. though it would be better if you assign the row id as the value for your dropdown so that you can easily find the rest of the data

Comment: You can write a function for the `onchange` property of the dropdown (select) which makes an ajax call to fetch the missing data.